# hds.item(i) is null or not an object in locking grid with filtering option (extjs 3.4)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I've created a Locking column grid with filtering options to all the columns.
now when i m trying to filter the last column , it throws the err

`hds.item(i) is null or not an object`

in updateColumnHeadings : function () {

```
    var view = this.grid.getView(),
        hds, i, len, filter;
    if (view.mainHd) {
        hds = view.mainHd.select('td').removeClass(this.filterCls);
        for (i = 0, len = view.cm.config.length; i < len; i++) {
            filter = this.getFilter(view.cm.config[i].dataIndex);
            if (filter && filter.active) {
                hds.item(i).addClass(this.filterCls);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

of filtering .ux part, `view.cm.config.length=10` and `i=8` i.e its not taking the locked column

(here no. of columns ,from last, throwing err= no. of locked column, i.e the length mismatch)

how to resolve this error

or am i missing some thing while coding , so `view.mainHd` is taking only unlocked column.. pls help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the locking header which was not cosidered when filtering applied

```
// Over-writing the filter function to accomodate Locking grid 
    Ext.LockingFilter = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters, {
        updateColumnHeadings : function () {
            var view = this.grid.getView(),
                hds, i, len, filter, lockLen;
            if (view.lockedHd) {
                lockLen = view.lockedHd.select('td').elements.length;
                hds = view.lockedHd.select('td').removeClass(this.filterCls);
                for (i = 0, len = lockLen; i < len; i++) {
                    filter = this.getFilter(view.cm.config[i].dataIndex);
                    if (filter && filter.active) {
                        hds.item(i).addClass(this.filterCls);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (view.mainHd) {
                var mainLen = view.mainHd.select('td').elements.length;
                hds = view.mainHd.select('td').removeClass(this.filterCls);
                for (i = 0, len = mainLen; i < len; i++) {
                    filter = this.getFilter(view.cm.config[i+lockLen].dataIndex);
                    if (filter && filter.active) {
                        hds.item(i).addClass(this.filterCls);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```